# Matrix multiplication not working in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix

I made a program that calculates product of all elements in column of a 2D array and stores that value in another 1D array. This is my code:

```
void product_of_col(int n)
{
    int i, j, product;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        product = 1;
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            product *= a[j][i];
        b[i] = product;
    }
}
```

This function works fine, but when I change

```
for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    product *= a[j][i];
```

to

```
for(j = 0; j < n; j++, product *= a[j][i]);
```

every product is equal to 0. I runned this code on Ideone and it didn't work. I also made a function that calculates the sum of all elements in the same column and it works fine for both codes.

Can anyone tell me why isn't the second code working?

Comment: lol, gotta love tabloid-style SO titles like, "Multiplication not working in C++". Anyway, are you sure `j` isn't being incremented in `j++, product *= a[j][i]` *before* it's used in `a[j][i]`? This is one of those cases where you can't necessarily rely on when `j` will be incremented, either before or after the expression that comes after the comma.

Comment: which compiler you are using?

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks

Comment: Code::Blocks isn't a compiler. It's an IDE. You have a compiler installed somewhere that Code::Blocks is using.

Comment: Changed title to "Matrix multiplication...", otherwise it implies there is something wrong with the multiplication operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the order wrong. Replace `for(j = 0; j < n; j++, product *= a[j][i]);` with `for(j = 0; j < n; product *= a[j][i], j++);`

Comment: On the last iteration, you accidentally accessed one index beyond n - 1 and the number in there must have been 0 because you initialised a big matrix with 0 and used only a n by n one.

Comment: The product was 0, the sum was unchanged ==> 0

Comment: Depends on the compiler, there is no guarantee this will work.

Comment: Actually, it will always work because when you have comma separated instructions, the first one will execute first.

Comment: The question was "Can anyone tell me why isn't the second code working?" and here is the answer. Also, comma separated instructions will execute in order.

Comment: NO http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order. a comma operator is exactly the same as `int& comma_operator(int& a, int& b) {return a;}`. There is no promise in the evaluation order on operands, only that the first argument will be the one that is returned. There is **nothing** in the standard that says that it can't do something like: 'int& x = j++; product *= a[j][i]; return x;`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: C++11 §5.18/1 "Every value computation and side effect associated with the left expression
is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the right expression". I.e. you're wrong. Also, I'm unable to find anything resembling your claim in the reference you cited.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf With the coresponding footnote "However, an invocation of an overloaded comma operator is an ordinary function call; hence, the evaluations of its argument expressions are unsequenced relative to one another" So its much safer to assume it is not sequenced.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: re "much safer to assume", no, in basic C++ programming it is decidedly *not* safer to lend more weight to vague associative feelings than to concrete reality. here we're dealing with the built-in comma operator, that's reality.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams the page you linked to says the same thing as the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your second snippet the expression `j++` gets executed *before* the expression `product *= a[j][i]` because of the way the comma operator works.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is something that you (probably) didn't learn in your C++ class. I know I sure as heck didn't.

## the comma operator

You probably know about the term "operator" in c++. You have +-=*/, ect. What you probably DIDN'T know is there is an comma operator (`,`). What the heck does the comma operator do? Whell basically, it evaluates everything in a statement, but *returns* only the first value. so i can do

```
int a = 1,2,3,4;
```

and a will only equal 1. Additionally, I can do

```
int x = 5; int y = 10;
int z = (y*=2), (x*=2);
std::cout << x << ',' << y << ',' << z << std::endl;
```

which will output 10, 20, and 20. What you are ACTUALLY doing in a for loop is calling this comma operator. In your case, we are looking at the statement

j++, product *= a[j][i]

I find it helpful to think of this as the following call:

const int& comma_operator(const int& a,const int& b) {return a;}
   comma_operator(j++,produce*=a[j][i]);

Now that you understand what the comma is actually doing, lets look at the concept of order of evaluation.

## order of evaluation

C++ makes NO promises on what order arguments to a function call or operator is called, just that they are all called before the function or operator is run. This may seem counter intuitive: you may be thinking to yourself, why doesn't it just run from left to right?

Well, this would tie the hand of the compiler in a lot of cases where it could optimize the crap out of your code. The common example would be:

int x; int y; int z = x/y+x%y.

In this case, most CPU's can calculate `x/y` and `x%y` with the same instruction. Certainly, this doesn't make sense to you, but the first argument to plus and the second argument to plus are calculated at the SAME time rather than sequentially.

C++ only guarantees that the code will behave the same as you wrote it logically, not exactly as you wrote it. And operand evaluation order is not part of that logic.

So just use `for(j = 0; j < n; j++) product *= a[j][i];` and you'll be happy.

Comment: -1 the "order of evaluation" section, while not literally wrong as I'm writing this comment, is irrelevant and strongly misleading.

Answer (score 0):

`Can anyone tell me why isn't the second code working?`

In your second code,

`for(j = 0; j < n; j++, product *= a[j][i]);`

You are incrementing `j` before `product *= a[j][i])` executes.So,Just change the order like :

```
for(j = 0; j < n; product *= a[j][i], j++);
```